# GWT Label Linked to URL with #

Tags: gwt

My GWT App has a list of labels.

When you click a gwt label, the browser does a GET request on a URL.

Sometimes, the URL can include multiple hash tags. This can occur when a user wants to search for particular tags, example: #bugFixed #newBug.

However, when clicking the label, only the first hash tag gets encoded to `%23`.

As a result, IE will redirect to the main page since it doens't like the un-encoded hash tag (#). Chrome and Firefox can handle the un-encoded # and render the page correctly.

Thanks

Comment: And the question is? We need to see your code if you want us to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should [try encoding the url](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/1.5/com/google/gwt/http/client/URL.html#encodeComponent%28java.lang.String%29)

URL.encode("whatever#"); will not do anything to the #

so be sure to use

URL.encodeComponent("whatever#");

Comment: Indeed, my problem was that I did not even call encodeComponent(...) on the given URL. Thanks.